# Checking the entry before adding it

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I need help,
I need a query that will check and will not allow adding a new entry as long as the value in the datanumber column does not repeat, but on the condition that the name is the same in the dataname column.
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHi2s.png)

Scenario:
I am adding a new entry [dataname] [datanumber]:

1. SENIOR | 3 - write
2. WEB | 2 - write
3. SENIOR | 2 - unable to write
4. ADMIN | 2 - write
5. ADMIN | 2 - unable to write

Comment: INSERT IGNORE perhaps - depends what you want to happen when discarding

Comment: You could write an insert trigger and in there check the values. You can cancel the insert in a trigger like this: `signal sqlstate '45000'` What MySQL version do you use?

Comment: 10.1.37-MariaDB

Comment: Mariadb is not mysql have added tag.

Comment: It is not totally clear, to me at least, what you are actually asking here

Answer (score 0):

Solution below

```
ALTER TABLE my_table_name 
ADD CONSTRAINT MyUniqueConstraint UNIQUE(dataname, datanumber)
```